# Sharing Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, share, excel-2013

Is there a file format that saves everything in your workbook to data? I basically want to remove all formulas quickly.

This is because I regularly have to share the updated version of a report I run with others via email, but when others try and open the spreadsheet on their PCs their version of the workbook data always gets messed up. This is because the workbook in question uses external workbooks and updates every time you open it.

I know I could C&P all the data as values, but this would take a long time as there are multiple sheets with huge amounts of data and I have to share this report regularly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the users need any interactivity? How many worksheets do they need to use? Perhaps printing to PDF would suffice?

Comment: A little macro which loops through sheets and writes/copies values would no nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I missed that you already know about Pasting Value.

Another option is, save the file in "csv" format. It preserve the values. But you have to do it for every sheet.

---

1. Press Ctrl+A to select whole excel sheet
2. Right click and select "Paste Special"
3. Then click on second option "Values"

This will convert the formula to values and you can share without worrying.

Comment: Poster already stated that Copy and paste special values is too much work so this does not contribute to a solution.